# Using run with anonymous procedures

Tags: netlogo

I am new to netlogo and I am having trouble understanding the performance issues related to using run with anonymous procedures.

My main concern is whether using run or runresult with an anonymous procedure incurs performance penalties or if this is something related to using run/runresult with string input only.

Thanks

## Some code :

My understanding is that you can achieve the same result with the following *two* different ways (there might be more but like I said I'm just starting with netlogo so these are the ones I can come up with):

```
to-report list-made-up-of-empty-lists? [ a-list ]

  let helper [ [ arg ] -> ( reduce and ( map empty? arg ) )]

  report ( map helper ( list a-list ) )

end
```

vs

```
to-report list-made-up-of-empty-lists? [ a-list ]

  let helper [ [ arg ] -> ( reduce and ( map empty? arg ) )]

  report ( list ( runresult helper a-list ) )

end
```

What's the difference?

Also, in the documentation it is stated that something like `runresult ( word "helper " a-list )` should work in principle but I can't make it run (I get runtime errors).

Shouldn't this last line evaluate correctly? What am I doing wrong? Also, in what sense can `runresult` '*run*' strings?

Comment: they both produce the same output for any valid input I have tried on them; true, `runresult ( word "sum " [1 2 3] )` works as expected; why doesn't `runresult ( word "helper " a-list )` evaluate correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing an anonymous procedure is significantly quicker than running a string. The issue is that the string needs to be converted to some executable code, then executed.

If you're comparing user defined functions vs anonymous procedures, that's a different story and dependent on use case. For example, if you have a for loop and create an anonymous function inside the loop, rather than creating it once outside the loop (or pre-defining it), you'd potentially start to see a slow down.

Netlogo's Run documentation:

```
run command  
(run command input1 ...)  
run string  
runresult reporter 
(runresult reporter input1 ...)  
runresult string  

The run form expects the name of a command, an anonymous command, or a string containing commands. This agent then runs them.

The runresult form expects the name of a reporter, an anonymous reporter, or a string containing a reporter. This agent runs it and reports the result.
```

Furthermore, the reason why your code won't work with a string is due to the following: Netlogo's string commands can't set/read local variables. Your helper is a local variable.

See the documentation:

> Anonymous procedures may freely read and/or set local variables and
>   procedure inputs. Trying to do the same with strings may or may not
>   work and should not be relied on.

Comment: sure, but that's just bad set-up of the code; it's not about anonymous procs per se;  in the context of my examples above how would one "run a string"?

Comment: Netlogo's run allows strings, anonymous procedures, or functions. Here's an example of running a string that creates 5 turtles. run "crt 5"

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see why `runresult ( word "helper " a-list )` doesn't run inside my reporter